# How to delete a object in a nested array on which you do not know the numbers of nesting levels

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I am trying to figure out how can I remove an element from an array in mongoDb C# driver that has multiple levels of nesting.

This is my model structure:

```
 public class CategoryEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryEntity> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

As it can be seen, the model may have multiple levels of nesting by itself.

The client may send me an Id that is from the parent category or from one of the nested categories.

What I have tryed is to select all the categories from the context of the companyId and to iterate in memory to find the one I am looking for, and then to update based on the root category. But this is not a performant query.

Is there any way to be able to delete the nested element by the category Id that I recieve from client?

Comment: is the category Id guaranteed to be unique for all elements?

Comment: Yes I am using Guids..... the categoryId is the Id in the model I provided